# TimeStamp syntax to appear 24 Hrs Timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp, time-series

I am using

```
var TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
var TZ = "GMT-7";
```

in my script code of Google document

I want it to be convert into 24 hrs timestamp

What changes should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace `hh` by `HH`
2. Remove `a`

Example

```
function myFunction() {
  var TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2020,5,5,18,23,3), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
  Logger.log(date)
};
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats